# redmine slow startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

We are running Redmine 1.0 on Apache/2.2.3 with Passenger and ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5. The hardware is a 512MB Linode VPS. We are experiencing a 5-6 second delay when accessing Redmine for the first time in a period. After we have accessed it, the pages load very fast. Is this a misconfiguration or expected behavior? Anything we can do to make our developers a little happier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to keep an application instance up for a longer time is to modify:

```
PassengerPoolIdleTime
```

See [Phusion Passenger users guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_resource_control_and_optimization_options) for more info on this.

So far I have good experience setting it to 3600.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any way to keep it in memory after first launch to avoid future delays?

**Edit:** `PassengerPoolIdleTime 0` works like a charm. How did I miss that option?

Answer (score 3):

Its typical behavior for just about any Rails app, at least in my experience.  Its particularly true of an app as large as Redmine.  The load time is because you're actually starting an executable and loading the app into memory on that first launch.